# Creating a new custom PostGIS function

Tags: postgis, geometry, function

I'd like to create a new, custom PostGIS function that would return a point geometry from a polygon that I can use for generating label points from a polygon, but I am not sure how to go about composing the function itself.

My goal is really simple...

1. generate initial label points for all polygons using ST_Centroid,
2. Test the label point to ensure that it falls on the surface of the polygon,
3. For centroids not on the surface of the polygon, fall back to ST_PointOnSurface.

This would mean most label points are at the Centroid, but ensure that irregular and "C" shaped polygons would have the label point at least somewhere on the surface.  I feel like the psuedo-code would look something like this:

```
SELECT gid,
  CASE 
    WHEN ST_Intersects(ST_Centroid(x.geom), x.geom) THEN ST_Centroid(x.geom)
    ELSE ST_PointOnSurface(x.geom)
  END AS geom
FROM x
```

Comment: Check the DDL of the existing functions in the public schema of your database - ST_Buffer for example - check the language specifics and how parameters are passed and how they are used in the function itself. While I don't completely understand the language, the basics of inputs and outputs can be understood using existing postgis functions as examples.

Comment: What would you call such a custom function?...

Comment: @CyrilMikhalchenko How about ST_CentroidOnSurface () ???

Comment: Yes, Okey,...  

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, I present another original geometric custom function as a built-in CTE.

Create a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_CentroidOnSurface(
geom GEOMETRY
)
RETURNS GEOMETRY AS
$BODY$
WITH
    tbla AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom geom),
    tblb AS (SELECT ST_Centroid(geom) geom FROM tbla),
    tblc AS (SELECT (a.geom) geom FROM tblb a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
    tbld AS (SELECT ST_PointOnSurface(geom) geom FROM tbla),
    tble AS (SELECT (a.geom) geom FROM tbld a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblb b WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)))
    SELECT (geom) geom FROM (SELECT * FROM tblc UNION SELECT * FROM tble) foo
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL
```

Run the function to execute:

`SELECT ST_CentroidOnSurface(geom) geom FROM <name_table>`

And check the result.

Test it hot, because this is the "hot pie that I just pulled out of my oven"...

variant 2

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ST_CentroidOnSurface(
geom GEOMETRY
)
RETURNS GEOMETRY AS
$BODY$
WITH
    tbla AS (SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom geom),
    tblb AS (SELECT ST_Centroid(geom) geom FROM tbla),
    tblc AS (SELECT (a.geom) geom FROM tblb a JOIN tbla b ON ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)),
    tbld AS (SELECT (a.geom) geom FROM tbla a WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tblb b WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom))),
    tble AS (SELECT ST_PointOnSurface(geom) geom FROM tbld)
    SELECT (geom) geom FROM (SELECT * FROM tblc UNION SELECT * FROM tble) foo
$BODY$
LANGUAGE SQL
```

Comment: That is DOPE!  It works really well, and fast.  I appreciate you sharing not only how to configure the function, but building the function itself!  Great work.

Comment: I am glad that I helped you and others...